# Перевод строковой переменной в числовую

Tags: c, переменные

Нужно написать программу: строкой вводим 1 слагаемое, 2 слагаемое, строку для поиска. Программа переводит строку в число и считает. Потом нужно посчитать кол-во совпадений в строке. Для этого полученный результат нужно опять перевести в строковую переменную. Для этого я хочу использовать sprintf, но он почему-то не работает. Пишет "error C2664: `sprintf`: невозможно преобразовать параметр 2 из "`double`" в "`const char *`". Что я делаю не так? Есть ли замена `sprintf`?
Вот фрагмент моей программы

```
int main(void)

{

    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
    char a1c[255], a2c[255], f; //первое слагаемое, второе слагаемое и строка для проверки
    double a1d, a2d, f1; //первое слагаемое, второе слагаемое и сумма

    printf("Введите первое слагаемое: ");
    gets(a1c); //если использовать scanf вместо gets, программа работает некорректно
    printf("Введите второе слагаемое: ");
    gets(a2c);
    a1d=atof(a1c);
    a2d=atof(a2c);
    f1=a1d+a2d;   
    sprintf("%f", f1);   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

RTFM, однако (и C++ тут никаким боком):

```
SYNOPSIS
       #include <stdio.h>

       int printf(const char *format, ...);
       int fprintf(FILE *stream, const char *format, ...);
       int sprintf(char *str, const char *format, ...);
       int snprintf(char *str, size_t size, const char *format, ...);
```